# How to make dictionary data in json format in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am new in python and tried to understand the working with dictionaries operations but stuck in between.

I have data like below:

```
[{'mesure':'10', 'name': 'mumbai', 'age': '15', 'class':'kg1'}, {'mesure':'20', 'name': 'hyd', 'age': '20', 'class':'kg2'},{'mesure':'11', 'name': 'mumbai', 'age': '145', 'class':'kg6'}, {'mesure':'21', 'name': 'hyd', 'age': '20', 'class':'kg2'}, {'mesure':'40', 'name': 'pune', 'age': '30', 'class':'kg4'}, {'mesure':'30', 'name': 'chennai', 'age': '25', 'class':'kg3'}, {'mesure':'41', 'name': 'pune', 'age': '30', 'class':'kg7'}, {'mesure':'22', 'name': 'hyd', 'age': '20', 'class':'kg2'}{'mesure':'12', 'name': 'mumbai', 'age': '40', 'class':'kg7'}, {'mesure':'46', 'name': 'pune', 'age': '30', 'class':'kg8'}]

I want to convert it in format like:

[{"Name": "mumbai",
        "data": [{'mesure':'10', 'name': 'mumbai', 'age': '15', 'class':'kg1'}, 
                 {'mesure':'11', 'name': 'mumbai', 'age': '145', 'class':'kg6'}, 
                 {'mesure':'12', 'name': 'mumbai', 'age': '40', 'class':'kg7'}]}

{"Name": "hyd", 
           "data":[{'mesure':'20', 'name': 'hyd', 'age': '20', 'class':'kg2'},
                   {'mesure':'21', 'name': 'hyd', 'age': '20', 'class':'kg2'},
                    {'mesure':'22', 'name': 'hyd', 'age': '20', 'class':'kg2'}]}

{"Name": "pune", 
             "data":[{'mesure':'40', 'name': 'pune', 'age': '30', 'class':'kg4'}, 
                      {'mesure':'41', 'name': 'pune', 'age': '30', 'class':'kg7'}, 
                      {'mesure':'46', 'name': 'pune', 'age': '30', 'class':'kg8'}]}]
```

I Tried:

```
def dir_data(data):
    main_list = []
    main_dir = []
    for i in data:
        names = i["name"]
        main_dir.append({"name": names, "data": i})
    print(main_dir)


if __name__== "__main__":
    data = [{'mesure':'10', 'name': 'mumbai', 'age': '15', 'class':'kg1'}, {'mesure':'20', 'name': 'hyd', 'age': '20', 'class':'kg2'},{'mesure':'11', 'name': 'mumbai', 'age': '145', 'class':'kg6'}, {'mesure':'21', 'name': 'hyd', 'age': '20', 'class':'kg2'}, {'mesure':'40', 'name': 'pune', 'age': '30', 'class':'kg4'}, {'mesure':'30', 'name': 'chennai', 'age': '25', 'class':'kg3'}, {'mesure':'41', 'name': 'pune', 'age': '30', 'class':'kg7'}, {'mesure':'22', 'name': 'hyd', 'age': '20', 'class':'kg2'}{'mesure':'12', 'name': 'mumbai', 'age': '40', 'class':'kg7'}, {'mesure':'46', 'name': 'pune', 'age': '30', 'class':'kg8'}]

    dir_data(data)
```

I tried above code but couldn't get exact output so please guide me to get it....

Thank you

Comment: you want to change the structure of your list of dictionaries, but this isn't related to JSON

Comment: ok....can you help me get recommended output

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do exactly? The question isn't very clear. Dictionaries in Python are a data-type, while JSON is a way of representing data-types, such as lists, and dictionaries, as ASCII  text. The Python syntax for creating a dictionary, is virtually identical to that of JSON. Perhaps that's why you confused the two?

Comment: Start by fixing the syntax error..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    def dir_data(data):
        items = []
        names = []
        for i in data:
            if i['name'] not in names:
                items.append({"Name": i['name'], "data": [i]})
                names.append(i['name'])
            else:
                iname = names.index(i['name'])
                items[iname]['data'].append(i)
    return items

    data = [{'mesure':'10', 'name': 'mumbai', 'age': '15', 'class':'kg1'},
    {'mesure':'20', 'name': 'hyd', 'age': '20', 'class':'kg2'},
    {'mesure':'11', 'name': 'mumbai', 'age': '145', 'class':'kg6'},
    {'mesure':'21', 'name': 'hyd', 'age': '20', 'class':'kg2'},
    {'mesure':'40', 'name': 'pune', 'age': '30', 'class':'kg4'},
    {'mesure':'30', 'name': 'chennai', 'age': '25', 'class':'kg3'},
    {'mesure':'41', 'name': 'pune', 'age': '30', 'class':'kg7'},
    {'mesure':'22', 'name': 'hyd', 'age': '20', 'class':'kg2'},
    {'mesure':'12', 'name': 'mumbai', 'age': '40', 'class':'kg7'},
    {'mesure':'46', 'name': 'pune', 'age': '30', 'class':'kg8'}
    ]
    print(dir_data(data))
```

Try that one.

Answer (score 3):

I can see the code you have written seems to be working but, you haven't returning the function, comma missing in data and also there is some mistakes in the way of call the function.
Just call the function like this,

```
def dir_data(data):
    main_list = []
    main_dir = []
    for i in data:
        names = i["name"]
        main_dir.append({"name": names, "data": i})
    return(main_dir)

data = [{'mesure':'10', 'name': 'mumbai', 'age': '15', 'class':'kg1'}, {'mesure':'20', 'name': 'hyd', 'age': '20', 'class':'kg2'},{'mesure':'11', 'name': 'mumbai', 'age': '145', 'class':'kg6'}, {'mesure':'21', 'name': 'hyd', 'age': '20', 'class':'kg2'}, {'mesure':'40', 'name': 'pune', 'age': '30', 'class':'kg4'}, {'mesure':'30', 'name': 'chennai', 'age': '25', 'class':'kg3'}, {'mesure':'41', 'name': 'pune', 'age': '30', 'class':'kg7'}, {'mesure':'22', 'name': 'hyd', 'age': '20', 'class':'kg2'},{'mesure':'12', 'name': 'mumbai', 'age': '40', 'class':'kg7'}, {'mesure':'46', 'name': 'pune', 'age': '30', 'class':'kg8'}]
dir_data(data)
```

Comment: hello dinesh, your output is not comming like i want please see in question

Comment: Hey @pavan I didn't went through the logic you did and I just saw the errors which I faced from your code. Give me sometime lemme try to figure it out.

Comment: @pavan Hope you got the solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can get desired solution by using below code

```
test_data = [{'mesure': '10', 'name': 'mumbai', 'age': '15', 'class': 'kg1'}, {'mesure': '20', 'name': 'hyd', 'age': '20', 'class': 'kg2'}, {'mesure': '11', 'name': 'mumbai', 'age': '145', 'class': 'kg6'}, {'mesure': '21', 'name': 'hyd', 'age': '20', 'class': 'kg2'}, {'mesure': '40', 'name': 'pune', 'age': '30', 'class': 'kg4'}, {'mesure': '30', 'name': 'chennai', 'age': '25', 'class': 'kg3'}, {'mesure': '41', 'name': 'pune', 'age': '30', 'class': 'kg7'}, {'mesure': '22', 'name': 'hyd', 'age': '20', 'class': 'kg2'}, {'mesure': '12', 'name': 'mumbai', 'age': '40', 'class': 'kg7'}, {'mesure': '46', 'name': 'pune', 'age': '30', 'class': 'kg8'}]

dic = dict()
for i in test_data:
    dic.setdefault(i['name'].title(),[]).append(i)
result = [{"name":k ,"data":v} for k,v in dic.items()]
```

Output

```
 [{'data': [{'class': 'kg4', 'age': '30', 'name': 'pune', 'mesure': '40'},
            {'class': 'kg7', 'age': '30', 'name': 'pune', 'mesure': '41'},
            {'class': 'kg8', 'age': '30', 'name': 'pune', 'mesure': '46'}], 'name': 'Pune'},

  {'data': [{'class': 'kg3', 'age': '25', 'name': 'chennai', 'mesure': '30'}], 'name': 'Chennai'}, 

  { 'data': [{'class': 'kg2', 'age': '20', 'name': 'hyd', 'mesure': '20'},
               {'class': 'kg2', 'age': '20', 'name': 'hyd', 'mesure': '21'},
               {'class': 'kg2', 'age': '20', 'name': 'hyd', 'mesure': '22'}], 'name': 'Hyd'},
                {
      'data': [{'class': 'kg1', 'age': '15', 'name': 'mumbai', 'mesure': '10'},
               {'class': 'kg6', 'age': '145', 'name': 'mumbai', 'mesure': '11'},
               {'class': 'kg7', 'age': '40', 'name': 'mumbai', 'mesure': '12'}], 'name': 'Mumbai'}]
```

Comment: Hello, if I return result then no output is comming. can you plz tell me why this is going

Comment: @pavan Just run the code you will get output. I guess you are doing some mistake while create method

Comment: if i run above code as it is then it will run successfully but if i put in method and return result then nothing come in output

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
import json

data = [{'mesure':'10', 'name': 'mumbai', 'age': '15', 'class':'kg1'}, {'mesure':'20', 'name': 'hyd', 'age': '20', 'class':'kg2'},{'mesure':'11', 'name': 'mumbai', 'age': '145', 'class':'kg6'}, {'mesure':'21', 'name': 'hyd', 'age': '20', 'class':'kg2'}, {'mesure':'40', 'name': 'pune', 'age': '30', 'class':'kg4'}, {'mesure':'30', 'name': 'chennai', 'age': '25', 'class':'kg3'}, {'mesure':'41', 'name': 'pune', 'age': '30', 'class':'kg7'}, {'mesure':'22', 'name': 'hyd', 'age': '20', 'class':'kg2'},{'mesure':'12', 'name': 'mumbai', 'age': '40', 'class':'kg7'}, {'mesure':'46', 'name': 'pune', 'age': '30', 'class':'kg8'}]


def dir_data(data):
    # set guarantees the uniqueness of each name
    names = set([item['name'] for item in data])

    main_dir = []

    # collect the data for each name
    for name in names:
        name_data = [d for d in data if d['name']==name]
        main_dir.append({"Name":name,"data":name_data})

    return json.dumps(main_dir)
```

Comment: Hello Sir, nothing is going to print

Comment: yeap eddited, forgot the "return"

Comment: still nothing returning

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution which will give you the exact result as described by you:

```
def checkKey(dict, key): 
    if key in dict: 
        return True
    else: 
        return False 

def dir_data(data):
    for item in test:
        if checkKey(tem_dict, item['name']):
            tem_dict[item['name']].append(item)
        else:
            tem_dict[item['name']] = []
            tem_dict[item['name']].append(item)
    res_dict = {}
    res = []
    for item in tem_dict:
        print item
        res_dict['Name'] = item
        res_dict['data'] = tem_dict[item]

        res.append(res_dict)
        res_dict = {}
    return res
```

let me know if this works for you or not.